# Creating Gold Table on Delta lake

Tags: delta-lake

We have to create Gold tables on Delta from real time data
The data which is coming from backend is Real time and I want to insert and update them on real time in the gold table

Please provide any suggestions

Comment: are you using Databricks or OSS Delta?

Comment: Not Using Databricks

Comment: look here: https://aarfahrayees.medium.com/delta-lake-26e76469322c bronze/silver/gold are just names, everything will depend on how you process data.  If you're doing real-time, then follow instructions on how to use structured streaming for reading & writing data: https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-streaming.html